# Remove question mark and Enter/Exit Button in RISE (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

When using RISE in Jupyter Notebook, is there any possible way to not display the question mark (lower left corner) and the Exit/ Enter Button (upper left corner)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. Go to `main.js` located in `/jupyter/nbextensions/rise`, there delete both

```
buttonExit();
buttonHelp();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pressing the comma (,) will actually hide/reveal the x and ? buttons, as well as the chalkboard buttons.  To hide the controls, you need to uncheck the box in the settings with 'controls':

[image]

You can use shift + C or the Nbextensions menu from the main jupyter page to get to the RISE settings.

You can also set the slidenumber as blank to not show any slide numbers, and uncheck the option for the progress bar.  Then with controls, menu items, progress bar, and slide numbers gone, you have a clean presentation.

Related github issue: https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/244

Answer (score 0):

May be you are asking How to get
[image]
from
[image]

you just need to press "," in command mode